# Is Baytril antiinflammatory?

Tags: veterinarian

I have a kitten that has feline leukemia. It's sister died from it, without getting a correct diagnosis. The sister gasped for air, like someone having an allergic reaction, and the antibiotics I was prescribed (because the vet never diagnosed leukemia) did nothing to help, so she finally just died. But theother one lived, and I suspect it was because she was given something antiinflammatory, since I am told the dead one's actions sounded like an inflamed airway restricting breath. It also refused to eat, which matches. The survivor was given Baytril as an antibacterial measure, but shortly after began eating again and is now perfectly healthy (yes, she is a carrier, and is isolated indoors). So I have to wonder, was the Baytril antiinflammatory and opened her throat up? I know it is not recommended to use antiinflammatories WITH Baytril, but I can find no other information on the matter...

Answer (score 1):

Baytril is not antiinflammatory.
Its an antibiotic. It is an FDA approved antibiotic.
Basically it is a flouroquinolone. Its action is by inhibiting DNA of bacteria.
And using one time the therapeutic index value was not upto the mark.
But using the second dose of the tablet taken the therapeutic index and the patient get cured.
Therapeutic index is the value below which the required action of the drug does not meet.It is a comparison of the amount of a therapeutic agent that causes the therapeutic effect to the amount that causes toxicity.
Means before toxicity it gets the patient cured of the problem it is suffering from.
Reference: veterinary pharmacology by goodman and gillman.
Plumbs veterinary pharmacology